# Draw circle after map is loading in mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl-draw

I want to draw circle after map is loading. For example, when user click a button, it creates a circle on the map.

```
var center = turf.point(droneLocation);
var radius = 0.5;
var options = {
   steps: 80,
   units: 'kilometers'
 };

 var circle = turf.circle(center, radius, options);

 map.addLayer({
   "id": "circle-fill",
   "type": "fill",
   "source": {
     "type": "geojson",
     "data": circle
  },
  "paint": {
      "fill-color": "green",
      "fill-opacity": 0.3
    }
  });
```

This is the code but when I put these codes outside of the map.onload() function, it gives error

> Uncaught Error: Style is not done loading
> at Ze._checkLoaded (style.js:433)
> at Ze.addLayer (style.js:756)
> at Map.addLayer (map.js:1912)
> at map.js:211

What I want is the create circle after map is loading.

Comment: add the layer on `map.onload` and set the visibility to `true` only when you click on the button, is one way to go.

Comment: There is a map.once.load function that loads once when the map is loaded.